# Суммирование совпадающих значений в строках в pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть готовый DataFrame из двух столбцов.
Надо суммировать значение во втором столбце по совпадающим значениям из первого и вывести результат.
То есть, например, сумма продаж по каждой торговой точке.
Понимаю, что вопрос наипримитивнейший, но завис, и примера не найду.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде нашёл.

```py
df.groupby('нужный_столбец').sum()
```

Работает, суммирует по остальным столбцам. Правда, с предупреждением:

> :1: FutureWarning: The default value of
> numeric_only in DataFrameGroupBy.sum is deprecated.  In a future
> version, numeric_only will default to False.  Either specify
> numeric_only or select only columns which should be valid for the
> function.

Comment: Да, всё правильно. Предупреждение видимо потому, что у вас есть ещё какие-то столбцы в датафрейме, не числовые. Можете предварительно отобрать только нужные столбцы (то есть два или сколько вам нужно интересующих вас столбца - для группировки и суммы) и тогда уже делать `groupby`.

Comment: Да, так и есть, был текстовый столбец.
Создал новый датафрейм из оригинального, отобрав столбцы, и работал уже с ним. Ошибка ушла. Спасибо.